# Convert Image to Fax "Sound", Send via Twilio?

Tags: fax, twilio

Would it be possible to send a fax through Twilio's api?

If one could convert the image  into a properly formatted audio sample, then pipe that audio through a phone call placed using Twilio's API, could it be "heard" and decoded into the proper image by the fax machine on the other end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faxing requires a lot of back and forth "talking" between sender and recipient, so it's not as easy as playing the right sound while connected to a fax machine.

Use Phaxio.com instead of Twilio.com.

Comment: At the time of writing Phaxio costs $2/mo for an inbound number and 7-10 cents per page for sending and receiving.

Comment: Seems like an inexpensive way to build an in-house web-based fax gateway for an intranet.

Comment: Not sure why this is an accepted answer. Doesn't even point you in the right direction for programatically communicating with fax machines.

Comment: Because the answer was "No"

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Twilio now offers [Programmable Fax](https://www.twilio.com/fax) :)